# I2C instability

Tags: i2c

I2C was working great for over a month using an Adafruit Motor Hat, and an LSM303 accelerator/compass also on the interface passing through the Motor Hat and consuming 3v.  As a side note, power-wise, two HC-SR04 sensors attached to GPIOs and 5v.

`sudo i2cdetect -y 1` will show the devices, I'll run my robot control software and although the devices init, as soon as I send a command to the wheels my app will crash because the devices have disappeared and `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` will not show the devices.  That's happened a couple of times.  The devices would eventually come back with no known action causing them to return despite my best efforts at process of elimination.  Now I can't get them to come back.

There have been no updates to the OS.

As I make changes to diagnose, suggestions on where I should focus?

- Wiring/Soldering
- Power
- Failed Motor Hat
- Failed Pi

Steps taken without consistently providing a fix:

- A reboot worked once to restore the connections but never again.
- Enabled/disabled the I2C interface.
- Resoldered SCL/SDA.
- Tried disconnecting the LSM303
- Turned the battery supplying the motors off/on
- Disconnected the HC-SR04 sensors

I have another Pi but haven't tried swapping it in yet - I guess that is my next step even though that seems unlikely to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Mid-way through the post, see the question has a question mark at the end: As I make changes to diagnose, suggestions on where I should focus?

Comment: Since you've attended to every other hardware possibility, except a different pi ... I'd say it is likely that the unlikely is not as unlikely as you think

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have damaged the GPIO by feeding 5V from the sonar rangers back to the GPIO?

Try wiringPi's pintest utility or (my) pigpio's gpiotest to check the GPIO.

Comment: It's possible I did because I was originally feeding 5V - subsequently I divided the voltage but perhaps it was too late.  It turned out the Pi was the problem - swapped in another and it works fine.  :( Thanks.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it was the likely cause.